# GPG Error on Private Repo

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I am using a private repo on Ubuntu 14.04 and everything works as expected.

While trying to build an Image based on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS I am getting this error:

```
W: GPG error: s3://my-repo-path stable Release: The following signatures were invalid: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

This occurs after im adding the key like this:

```
$ aws s3 cp s3://my-repo-pth/key.pgp - | apt-key add
$ OK
$ apt-get update
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Is the key signed by a recognized entity (or self signed)?

Comment: as far as I know - self signed.

Comment: Well then you have to find out how to verify it and make sure it's in the right keyring